# Why does composedPath on event returns different value when delayed?

Tags: javascript, html

Because simply `path` doesn't exist on `MouseEvent` or `WheelEvent` type, I'm using an alternative: `composedPath` method. I couldn't experience a difference between them until now. I wrapped my `wheel` listener with `requestAnimationFrame`, and surprisingly with it `composedPath` returns an empty array. Just an example:

```js
window.addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log('at event:', Array.from(e.composedPath()));
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('after event:', Array.from(e.composedPath()));
  }, 0)
})
```

```css
#test {
  width: 120vw;
  height: 120vh;
}
```

```html
<div id='test'></div>
```

(it's advisable to check the browser's console, because `window` is a bit large to scroll through it)

If anyone has an idea how could I solve this problem, that would be great to know it, but the question is mainly to understand what makes the difference.

Answer (score 4):

The specification defines this behavior. At the end of the steps for [dispatching an event](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dispatching-events), we have:

> 5. (looping through ancestor elements adding them to the event's path)
>
> ...
>
> 8. Set *event*’s [path](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#event-path) to the empty list.

That is, in Step 5 the browser fills in the path information, and in Step 8 (after all event processing is done), the specification explicitly says the browser must clear the path information.

The specification characteristically doesn't say *why*, but [Kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido) [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62181537/why-does-composedpath-on-event-returns-different-value-when-delayed/74610934?noredirect=1#comment131699356_74610934) that [the commit adding Step 8](https://*%20The%20path%20you%20get%20back%20is%20determined%20in%20part%20by%20the%20%60currentTarget%60%20of%20the%20event%20you%20call%20%60composedPath%60%20on%20(in%20particular%20in%20relation%20to%20the%20shadow%20DOM),%20which%20of%20course%20varies%20depending%20on%20what%20event%20listener%20is%20active.%20Once%20the%20event%20has%20been%20fully%20dispatched,%20%60currentTarget%60%20is%20set%20to%20%60null%60.%20If%20you%20work%20through%20the%20steps%20of%20%5B%60composedPath%60%5D%5B2%5D,%20you%27ll%20see%20that%20even%20if%20the%20path%20information%20hadn%27t%20been%20cleared%20when%20dispatch%20was%20complete,%20calling%20%60composedPath%60%20when%20%60currentTarget%60%20is%20%60null%60%20would%20just%20return%20the%20path%20%60%5Bnull%5D%60%20(if%20I%27m%20reading%20the%20steps%20correctly),%20which%20wouldn%27t%20be%20of%20any%20use.) is primarily concerned with the handling of event paths in relation to the Shadow DOM. In any case, the path you get back is determined in part by the `currentTarget` of the event you call `composedPath` on (in particular in relation to the shadow DOM), and the `currentTarget` only has meaning when an event is actively being dispatched (once the event has been fully dispatched, `currentTarget` is set to `null`). Even if the path weren't cleared by Step 8, if I'm reading the steps of [`composedPath`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-event-composedpath) correctly, it would just return the path `[null]` when called when `currentTarget` is `null`, which wouldn't be of any use. (It also makes sense for non-Shadow-DOM reasons: It's common for the event object to be closed over by functions that will never call `composedPath`, so it makes sense not to keep that information in memory unnecessarily. Any elements in the path that are later removed from the DOM would be cluttering up memory for no good reason. But the evidence suggests that's not the primary motivation for adding Step 8.)

If you need the path of the event, simply grab it during processing rather than after.

```
window.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const path = Array.from(e.composedPath(), (e) => e === window ? "window" : e.nodeName);
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(path);
    }, 0);
});
```

```js
window.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const path = Array.from(e.composedPath(), (e) => e === window ? "window" : e.nodeName);
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(path);
    }, 0);
});
```

```css
#test {
  width: 120vw;
  height: 120vh;
}
```

```html
<div id='test'></div>
```

Comment: It's less for memory than because of the shadow DOM. If you call `composedPath()` from inside a shadow DOM, you'll have your `currentTarget` set to a "shadow-element" and the `composedPath()` will also contain that "shadow-element". However when the event bubbles up outside of the shadow DOM, the `currentTarget` will be a "light DOM" element, and you won't be able to see the inner shadow elements. And so it is for the `composedPath()`

Comment: @Kaiido - That sounds like a better answer if you can give citations for the reasoning (as all I could do was guess at it, I couldn't provide citations), or at least an as-good answer even if you can't. :-) I'd be keen to read that answer if you post it.

Comment: Trying to walk back github's PR I can't really get hold of it and I'm a bit tired for today. Found https://github.com/whatwg/dom/issues/525 which might contain info or links. Also it seems the step 8 was introduced in https://github.com/whatwg/dom/pull/240 which links to https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/485 but no clear explanation as far as I can see.

Comment: Relevant commits are [ed94c9f](//github.com/whatwg/dom/commit/ed94c9f), [fc16564](//github.com/whatwg/dom/commit/fc16564) which contain a bit of explanation in their commit messages. It looks like this is closely related to Shadow DOM, and has a rationale similar to setting `currentTarget` to `null`, but this is a bit too deep of a rabbit hole for me today, as well…

Comment: @Kaiido - I've added the Shadow DOM explanation and made the answer a CW. The fact that one of the commits in [the PR you pointed to](https://github.com/whatwg/dom/pull/240/commits/e4912e677352a70c1a3d5a784597027d2e866e91) is all about the Shadow DOM and is what added Step 8 is, for me, very strong evidence. If you decide to post an answer at some point, though, I'll remove that from this one (probably remove this one entirely). Nice find!

Answer (score 2):

You can solve the problem by computing the `composedPath` once when the event fires, and store that in a variable for reuse inside the timeout.

```js
window.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const a = e.composedPath();
  console.log('at event:', Array.from(a).length);
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('after event:', Array.from(a).length);
  }, 0)
})
```

```css
#test {
  width: 120vw;
  height: 120vh;
}
```

```html
<div id='test'></div>
```

I'm a bit unsure as to why this is happening. It might be that they reuse the same Event over and over under the hood as an optimization in to save on memory usage. To reduce the number of times they need to allocate and deallocate memory. Which might end up being a big factor for performance on low end devices.