# Why event.composedPath() is empty array when inside `setTimeout`?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

Execute below code in you browser console, you will see the result.

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  console.log(111, e.composedPath());
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(222, e.composedPath());
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Okay, so the composed path isn't available after the event has finished being processed. And...? You know how to grab the path before the event processing is complete, so what's the question?

Comment: Quote MDN, _"The composedPath() method of the Event interface returns the event's path which is an array of the objects on which listeners **will be invoked**."_ - I guess this is due to the fact that any such listeners already have been invoked, by the time your delayed function runs.

Comment: Already asked here: [Why does composedPath on event returns different value when delayed?](/q/62181537/4642212), though without an answer that explains why this happens.

Comment: @CBroe - That quote is slightly misleading. While the event is still being processed, it also includes objects on which the listeners (if any) have already been invoked.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder _"While the event is still being processed"_ - but it already _has_ been processed, by the time the setTimeout callback executes, no?

Comment: @CBroe - Yes. I don't see how my sentence says otherwise? My point was that the MDN phrase *"... **will be** invoked..."* is slightly misleading.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ah okay, I see what you mean now. Will be invoked includes already _have_ been invoked, as long as the event processing is still going on.

Comment: FWIW, I've posted an answer to the [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62181537/4642212). Presumably it answers this question too, although it's not entirely clear to me what this question is. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Dang, I was [writing an answer](//i.stack.imgur.com/iLQwe.png), too, which adds quite a bit more context (I love these answers that take you on a journey of discovery, like a crime novel). I was going to try and find a possible rationale somewhere buried in the GitHub issues for the DOM spec, as well.

Comment: @SebastianSimon - If you haven't already, see Kaiido's comment on my answer. They claim it's mostly because of the shadow DOM. I've suggested that if they can provide a citation for that, it would be a better answer than mine, which just speculates. :-)